# Iterating over a list of characters, but not extending beyond the index

Tags: python, loops

I want to loop a string of characters; if a character meets a certain criterion, then I want to adjust the character immediately after it. Problem is, if the character in question is the last one in the string, and I want to adjust the character beyond that, then I'm beyond the index range.

How do I loop through a string without going beyond the index?

```
letters_of_name = ["j", "e", "l", "l", "o"]

def uppercase_specific_letters(letter):

    for ch_index, ch in enumerate(letters_of_name):
        if ch == letter:

            if letters_of_name[ch_index + 1] != ch:
                letters_of_name[ch_index + 1] = letters_of_name[ch_index + 1].upper()

            new_name = "".join(letters_of_name)
            return new_name
```

Comment: `if ch == letter and ch_index < len(letters_of_name) - 1:`?

Comment: That solved it. So, it's saying, "if the character equals the letter AND the character's index position is second last in the string, then . . . " Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a slice of the string that excludes the last character.

```
for ch_index, ch in enumerate(letters_of_name[:-1]):
```

Another option is to loop over just indexes using `range()`, and use length-1 as the limit instead of length.

```
for ch_index in range(len(letters_of_name)-1):
    ch = letters_of_name[ch_index]
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I especially like first solution, where I loop through all characters up to but not including the character in the last index position. I was on that track, but I wasn't entirely sure how to structure it inside enumerate(). That makes sense now -- thank you!